# php html how the page will just refresh not redirecting to other page and how will the form connect to database

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to implement a contact form the form has no error and running tnx to shank:) but how will this form will not redirect to other page instead reload the page and if all field has been filed up the form will refresh and have a new form:) tnx please help me i added some required function on the input. and how will i connect this to mysqli database using xampp

**contact.php:**

```
   <?php
   $dbhost = "localhost";
   $dbuser = "root";
   $dbpass = "ntf123";
   $db = "ntfcatering";
   $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db);
  ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>PHP Contact Form with Captcha</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form action="mailer.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" style="margin:0px;  font-  family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px; width:300px;"   onsubmit="MM_validateForm('from','','RisEmail','subject','','R','verif_box','','R','message'      ,'','R');return document.MM_returnValue">

  Your Name:<span class="required">*</span><br />
 <input required="required" name="name" type="text" id="name" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;    width:180px; height:14px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;"   value="<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>"/>
 <br />
 <br />

 Your e-mail:<span class="required">*</span><br />
 <input required="required" name="from" type="text" id="from" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;  width:180px; height:14px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;"  value="<?php echo $_GET['from'];?>"/>
 <br />
 <br />

 Subject:<br />
 <input required="required" name="subject" type="text" id="subject" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid  #CCCCCC; width:180px; height:14px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font- size:11px;" value="<?php echo $_GET['subject'];?>"/>
 <br />
 <br />

 Type verification image:<br />
 <input name="verif_box" type="text" id="verif_box" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid   #CCCCCC; width:180px; height:14px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-  size:11px;"/>
  <img src="verificationimage.php?<?php echo rand(0,9999);?>" alt="verification image,   type it in the box" width="50" height="24" align="absbottom" /><br />
   <br />

  <!-- if the variable "wrong_code" is sent from previous page then display the error  field -->
  <?php if(isset($_GET['wrong_code'])){?>
  <div style="border:1px solid #990000; background-color:#D70000; color:#FFFFFF;   padding:4px; padding-left:6px;width:295px;">Wrong verification code</div><br /> 
  <?php ;}?>

  Message:<span class="required">*</span><br />
    <textarea required="required" name="message" cols="6" rows="5" id="message" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; width:300px; height:100px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;"><?php echo $_GET['message'];?></textarea>
    <noscript><a href="http://www.thewebhelp.com" style="display:none;">contact form by   thewebhelp</a></noscript>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" style="margin-top:10px; display:block; border:1px     solid #000000; width:100px; height:20px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   font-size:11px; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:2px;   line-height:14px; background-color:#EFEFEF;" value="Send Message"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**verificationimage.php**

```
  <?php


   header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  $width = 50;
  $height = 24;

   $my_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

   imagefill($my_image, 0, 0, 0xFFFFFF);

   // add noise
  for ($c = 0; $c < 40; $c++){
      $x = rand(0,$width-1);
      $y = rand(0,$height-1);
      imagesetpixel($my_image, $x, $y, 0x000000);
     }

  $x = rand(1,10);
  $y = rand(1,10);

   $rand_string = rand(1000,9999);
   imagestring($my_image, 5, $x, $y, $rand_string, 0x000000);

  setcookie('tntcon',(md5($rand_string).'a4xn'));

  imagejpeg($my_image);
  imagedestroy($my_image);
 ?>



  mailer.php
  enter code here
  <?php
 $name = $_REQUEST["name"];
 $subject = $_REQUEST["subject"];
 $message = $_REQUEST["message"];
 $from = $_REQUEST["from"];
 $verif_box = $_REQUEST["verif_box"];

 $name = stripslashes($name); 
 $message = stripslashes($message); 
 $subject = stripslashes($subject); 
 $from = stripslashes($from); 

 if(md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']){
  $message = "Name: ".$name."\n".$message;
  $message = "From: ".$from."\n".$message;
  mail("adriantadeo14@rocketmail.com", 'Online Form: '.$subject,     $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n\n".$message, "From: $from");
  setcookie('tntcon','');
   } else {

   header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?  subject=$subject&from=$from&message=$message&wrong_code=true");
   exit;
  }
  ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
         <title>PHP Contact Form Redirect</title>
      </head>

        <body>
       </body>
       </html>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The basic program flow is as follows:  When the form is submitted the server is called which calls your php program.  Your php program must get the data that the user input into your form, put it in a data base, and then send the form back to you.  Mailer.php needs some work, quite a bit of it from the looks of it but you have a good start.

Comment: Create a really, really simple program, just to get it working.  Like 5 lines of code.  Then once you have the basics worked out flesh out the details.  Leave the data base stuff out of it at first if that helps.

Comment: so this? 

>if($_POST["name"] && $_POST["email"]&& $_POST["msg"]){  $name=$_POST["name"];  $email=$_POST["email"]; $msg=$_POST["message"];}
else{ exit("TRY AGAIN!");}
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ntfcatering`.`contacts` (`name`, `email`, `msg`, `join_date) VALUES ( ' ". $name ." ' ,' ". $email ." ' ,' ". $message ." ',NOW());";
if( mysqli_query($conn, $sql )) echo "food has been added!";

Comment: $Name = $_POST['name'];
echo "Got it";

Comment: I've been programming for 30+ years and I still create one, two and three line test programs from time to time with new things I don't understand to get basic features working before moving them into my code.

Comment: sry but i really cant understand what line of codes will i do

Comment: Put just this in your php file: "<?php $Name = $_POST['name']; echo "Got it"; ?>"  Then open your form something.htm in you browser and submit it.  You should get back "Got it" on your screen.  Get that working first.